# Eloquent finding the row with the max value with grouping

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, aggregate-functions

Hi I have the problem and solution here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html which is to find the row with the max of a certain column, grouped by some other value.

My question is how do I convert the query below to Eloquent format?

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
    FROM shop s1
    JOIN (
      SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
      FROM shop
      GROUP BY article) AS s2
ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [raw-expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions) ?

Comment: I have but I just couldn't get it to work somehow, I can only make it work when i put the entire SQL inside DB::select('query')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using raw Builder you can use below if using eloquent just remove table names and replace with your model instance

```
DB::table(DB::raw('shop as s1'))
   ->join(
       DB::raw('(SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price FROM shop GROUP BY article) as s2'), 
     function($query) {
       $query->on('s1.article', '=', 's2.article')
             ->on('s1.price', '=', 's2.price');
     })->get();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the raw table names, because there will be multiple hardcode table names in source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DB::query()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) which is straight forward. You can also get help from [Queries - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) to apply the joins or [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Shop::join('shop as shop2', 'shop.article', '=', 'shop2.article')
        ->groupBy('shop.article', 'shop.price')
        ->havingRaw('max(shop2.price) = shop.price')
        ->get()
```